How to combine an input and a function?
I want to make a program that uses a user's input and then return a result depending on what the user writes.
I made a km/h to m/s converter, but would like for users to input the km/h value and then the program can provide the result depending on the value the user entered. If that makes sense
This is what I have so far:
km_h = 1000
m_s =  3600

def conversion_of_units(converter):
    print (f'{converter} km/h are equal to {converter * km_h / m_s} m/s')

conversion_of_units(45)


It depends on how do you expect the input to occur, e.g. command line arguments, typing after being prompted, a fancy UI...

But there's nothing special about combining input with a function. How would you do it outside a function definition?

use the input() function.
km_h = 1000
m_s =  3600


def conversion_of_units(converter):
    print (f'{converter} km/h are equal to {converter * km_h / m_s} m/s')

user_input = input('Enter a value: ')

conversion_of_units(int(user_input))


Not a bad idea to check that input before using it. Never assume the user will do what you want or expect.

Definitely true! Validation is probably context dependent on what the input expects here, but it would certainly help to add checks beyond just validating that this is an integer.

I really appreciate your help broh!
